# Test site for evaluation of security solutions

Tags: security, testing, ddos

I need to create testbed for security solution. The plan is to set up webserver with some sort of web application running on it, hook up security solution, perform DDoS attack on web server and see if security solution can handle the attack. I am planning to use apache + php + mysql.

**Do you know any good site generators that would generate lot of php pages each with different complexity, some using database, some dont etc ?**

Now I am using local mirror of wiki (wikinews), but I feel that I need more complex sites.

Answer (score 1):

You may just want to find some opensource inventory management, or something along those lines. I don't know if you'll find exactly what you're asking, but just scouring for opensource webapps might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a linux machine, Apache Utils has ab (Apache benchmark tool).

This can be used to create a large load against your webserver easy enough.

```
ab -n 1000000 -c 100 http://yourserver/yourpage
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to simulate the scenario when you get a DoS attack on your web site. To be more fair you want to maximize the load on server by adding more database operations and similar activities.

In this case I'd suggest the way of having several pages with many database operations. As an example you can create a complex page and get a large number of copies of the same page using a simple program. By applying this approach on few pages of different complexities you will get the combination of pages you expect. :-)

Good luck with your security solution!!!